# Easy way to have multiple color versions of the same logo without duplicating?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a logo made of text and paths. Everything is blue. I also want an all white version, an all black version, and a version that has one word blue and one grey. The only way I know how to accomplish this is to copy and paste the entire group of objects into another artboard, or copy the file, and then just change the colors. I would have 5 or so versions of the same logo, just different colors.

But then if I tweak one object, I have to recreate that tweak in the other 4.

Is there any way to keep one version of the logo but link it to different color schemes?

Using Illustrator 2017

Comment: I found a suitable approach via the answer posted above.  In short, if you can turn the logo into a Dynamic Symbol, then use the symbol multiple places and change the colors there. If you make changes to the dynamic symbol, it automatically updates the multiple instances of the logo.

Answer (score 2):

Try using color overlays on the layers.  Or, if you import the file into photoshop, you can use smart objects/layer comps.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't color overlays done in Photoshop? Or, can you please explain how to do your suggestion in Illustrator only?

Comment: My apologies, overlays are applied in Photoshop.  You could try creating a custom 'graphic style' to apply to your logo.  The issue lies when you are trying to apply multiple different colors to the same lockup of shapes.
If your logo is a solid shape, and you only need to apply one color to it, you should be fine using graphic styles.
Hope this helps.